# populate multidimensional struct array with array data

Tags: arrays, swift

I have some arrays which I am filling with data in my application. So when I initialize it, the arrays are - to some part - empty.

When my arrays are filled with all nessecary data, I want to save them in a multidimensional array in order to populate a table with this data, which is ordered by sections.

However, I am struggling how to append this multidimensional array with data.

This is what I want to have in my multidimensional array in the end:

```
data in myServerInfo: 

serverInfo(
    [ping: "www.apple.com", serverStatusMain: "no data", statusImagesMain: "error"],

    [ping: "www.google.com", serverStatusMain: "no data", statusImagesMain: "error"],

    [ping: "www.amazon.com", serverStatusMain: "no data", statusImagesMain: "error"],

    [ping: "www.bla.com", serverStatusMain: "no data", statusImagesMain: "error"]
    )
```

My current implementation looks like this:

```
struct serverInfo {
    var pings: String
    var serverStatusMain: String
    var statusImageMain: String
}

var myServerInfo: [[serverInfo]] = []


let pings = ["www.apple.com", "www.google.com", "www.amazon.com", "www.bla.com"]
var statusImagesMain = ["error", "error", "error", "error"]
var serverStatusMain = ["no data", "no data", "no data", "no data"]

for i in serverStatusMain { //
    myServerInfo.append([serverInfo(pings: pings[i], serverStatusMain: serverStatusMain[i], statusImageMain: statusImagesMain[i])])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append it like this.

```
for i in 0..<serverStatusMain.count {
    myServerInfo.append(serverInfo(pings: pings[i], serverStatusMain: serverStatusMain[i], statusImageMain: statusImagesMain[i]))
}
```

You made 2 mistakes:

- You need `i` to have the *index* of the array to iterate through it.
- You need to append an instance of an array for which you don't need to enclose it within `[]`.

However if you need to append an array you can do it using the other append method.

```
myServerInfo.append(contentsOf: serverInfoArray) // serverInfoArrat would be an array -> [serverInfo]
```

Comment: Argh I now have the problem with using cellForRowAt IndexPath: Since it is multidimensional this solution its not working: "lblDescribtion.text = myServerInfo[indexPath.row].hosts". It sais "Value of type '[serverInfo]' has no member 'hosts'"

Comment: @Jake2Finn that is outside of the scope of the question. You should post another question.